# Why does water freeze at $0~^\circ\text{C}$ while poultry freezes at $-2.2~^\circ\text{C}$?

Tags: everyday-life, freezing

We all know the freezing point of water is $0~^\circ\text{C}$, however correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the freezing point of poultry (which I'm guessing means water in poultry) is $-2.2~^\circ\text{C}$.  If so, why is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we also all know that *salt* water has a freezing point much lower than 0$^\circ$C (and a boiling point higher than 100$^\circ$C). This is because of changes in the entropy of the solution (see [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression) for more details).

The cells in poultry (and the "stuff" in between the cells) don't contain pure, distilled water (which freezes at 0$^\circ$C), but "polluted" water (which freezes at temperatures slightly *below* 0$^\circ$C).

Actually, most organic things freeze at temperatures slightly off 0$^\circ$C for the same reasons. I remember a few of my colleagues doing an experiment on frozen salt-water fish, and they discovered that they couldn't bear the smell after a few hours, because they kept it at 0$^\circ$C (instead of the (roughly) -6$^\circ$C they should have kept it at to keep it frozen).